# Clip layer with geometry using OpenLayers 2

Tags: openlayers

How to clip a layer with a geometry (example is [this gist](https://gist.github.com/elemoine/b95420de2db3707f2e89#file-readme-md)) using OpenLayers 2?

Comment: Are you talking about this effect: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/layer-spy.html. If so, the short answer is you would have to write it yourself.

Comment: The slightly longer answer is that it involves pre and post compose events, that do not exist in OL2. You would also have to deal with all the different renderers in OL2, VML for IE, and SVG for everything else. Another issue with OL2 is that you have a base layer and other layers, whereas in OL3 you just have layers, which makes mixing them up at the rendering stage a lot easier. So, the longer answer, is you will to write it yourself, and it will be a lot of work.